# Soap Service Client DHL

Tags: web-services, soap

DHL soap service client returns server timeout error.I am using SOAP pakcage to create client.I have added full code.I have tested credentials and they are working fine.You can check (https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/soap/) for soap sample.

```
var soap = require('soap');
var apiWSDL = 'http://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/soap';
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer.from("*****" + ":" + "*****").toString("base64");
function getDetails() {

    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        
        soap.createClient(apiWSDL, { wsdl_headers: { Authorization: auth } }, function (err, client) {
            if(err) throw new Error(err);

            var args = {
            
                userHash:'',
                orderBy:'',
                pageSize:'2000',
                pageNumber:'1',
                userName:''
            }
            client.createShipmentOrder(args, function(err, result) {
                if(err) reject(err);
                if(!result) {
                    console.log('No result...')
                }
                var sets = result.getSetsResult.sets;
                console.log('i found '+sets.length+' results');
                if(sets.length) {
                        resolve(set);

                    } else {
                        resolve(set);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
    return p;
}
exports.getRandomSet = getDetails;
```

### ERROR

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 149.239.125.123:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '149.239.125.123',
  port: 80 }
```

Comment: Can you share the call you are making and what the response looks like?

Comment: i have shared call and error message.

Comment: issue was resolved by using new and correct api url, there was nothing wrong with API call.